# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by null

Tags: android, android-facebook

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Login"

            android:background="@drawable/nice_button"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to add Facebook login to my app following a tutorial. I am getting this error. I searched on the internet but did not get any solution. I pointed out that the problem is in the XML file Facebook button widget.

```js
05-14 00:59:52.399 28057-28057/com.donateblood.blooddonation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.donateblood.blooddonation, PID: 28057
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
   at com.donateblood.blooddonation.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:87)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: null
   at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
   at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset(FacebookSdk.java:735)
   at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
   at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
   at com.donateblood.blooddonation.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:87) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

```html
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;
    DB db;
    DBCursor cursor;
    GPSTracker gps ;
    DBCollection collection;
    Database dataobj = new Database();
    public static String email;
    public static String password;
    private CallbackManager mcallbackManager;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult>  mcallbackk = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accss = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile prof = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainGUI.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };
    @InjectView(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
    @InjectView(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_signup) TextView _signupLink;
    //GPSTracker gps;

    //public static Button myloc;
  // public static TextView myTxt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        LoginButton fbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LoginActivity.this);
        mcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        fbLogin.registerCallback(mcallbackManager,mcallbackk);

      // myloc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loc);
       // myTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

     /*   myloc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                gps=new GPSTracker(LoginActivity.this);
            }
        }); */
        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncLogin LoginThread = new AsyncLogin();
                LoginThread.execute();
            }
        });
        fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        public boolean flag =false;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            login();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (!validate()) {
                onLoginFailed();
                return;
            }
            _loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(flag==true){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onLoginSuccess();
            }
            if(flag==false){
                onLoginFailed();
            }
        }
        public void login() {
            email = _emailText.getText().toString();
            password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
            db = dataobj.getconnection();
            collection= db.getCollection("UserDetails");
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("email", email);
            query.put("password", password);
            cursor = collection.find(query);
            if(cursor.hasNext()){
                flag=true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }*/

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        gps=new GPSTracker(LoginActivity.this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainGUI.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed. Incorrect credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("Enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            _passwordText.setError("Enter password");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: For your future questions: if your stack trace is, for some reason, shifted 20 tabs to the right, please be kind and untab it 20 places to the left, so it is easier for people to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize();
```

It must be called from your Application class, not your Activity's.
As per [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/):

> sdkInitialize(Context, int)
>
> This function initializes the Facebook SDK, the behavior of Facebook
>   SDK functions are undetermined if this function is not called. It
>   should be called as early as possible.